# Possible Sender Reputation Impact in Multiple dedicated IP under One SAP domain. (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, deliverability, ip, sap

Is there anyone who have configured multiple dedicated IPs under one SAP domain?
we have 4 dedicated IPs under one SAP domain and I've wondered the possible impact that could occur in multiple IP environment. for example, one of IP among 4 IPs get lower sender reputation score, then would other IPs be affected from it? I'm curious whether Sender reputation score is evaluated at IP level or SAP domain level

any help would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the Email Service Provider.

Quote:

> Some inbox providers will put more emphasis on your domain reputation vs. your IP reputation, although many will look at both your IP and domain reputation when making decisions about whether or not your mail will make the inbox.

[https://sendgrid.com/en-us/blog/email-reputation-101-ip-reputation-vs-domain-reputation#:~:text=Key%20Differences%3A,especially%20with%20a%20dedicated%20IP](https://sendgrid.com/en-us/blog/email-reputation-101-ip-reputation-vs-domain-reputation#:%7E:text=Key%20Differences%3A,especially%20with%20a%20dedicated%20IP).

If an ESP looks at IP for reputation, any issue will be isolated to the affected  IPs. if an ESP looks at domain for reputation, a problem will be not limited by IP.

Comment: I see... I need to reconsider how to manage multiple IP... really thanks your help.